# jqplot - don't want to display / show the y axis

Tags: axis, show, jqplot

I am using the jqplot charting library from quite sometime.

I don't want to display the y2axis (i.e when I am working with multiple axes/series) 
Went through the documentation and found that 'show: false' will not show the axis.

Link here: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.show

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed it.

Here's what I did.

```
axes: {
    yaxis: {
    tickOptions: {
        show: false
    },
    rendererOptions: {
        drawBaseline: false
    }
}
```

Setting `tickoptions` to `false`, hides the axis labels and ticks and `drawBaseline: false` hides the axis line.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify `showTicks : false`

Here is a link on a working fiddle without yaxis ticks : http://jsfiddle.net/BLfRe/23/

Comment: Hi sdespont. Actually my question is not showing the y-axis. And not just the ticks. Thanx for the answer though. I appreciate your efforts : )

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jqplot and I wanted to hide the y2axis too in some case.
Using `plot1.axes.y2axis.show = false;` seems to work perfectly.

Can you put the piece of code you use in order to find what can cause your troubles?

Comment: I know this answer should be a comment but I can't comment yet since I'm new on stackOverflow.